# Problemas para usar sistema desenvolvido no React no Apache

Tags: react

Criei uma aplicação com React, e quando terminei de desenvolver dei `npm run build`, joguei o app no servidor Xampp para testar, mas quando acesso o sistema pelo servidor Xampp aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu App depois da build**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Falta um pouco de informação na sua pergunta. Como é a build que vc roda? É a padrão do react?

Comment: O problema provavelmente está na referência dentro do `index.html`. Nas referências dos scripts, coloque o src como `src="/build/static/<...>`